# uiRouter blocking redirect to server's static directory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to write a sequence that uploads json, converts it to xml and returns a file that is directly saved to disk by the browser. In my Factory `saveData` simply returns a $http promise, and my Controller has:

```
vm.saveFile = () ->
    console.log "Saving to file"
    Factory.saveData()
    .success (res) ->
        $location.url '/newfile.tcx'
```

I originally planned to have my express backend send a redirect, but that is ignored by angular $http, and so it is now implemented on the client side. If I go directly to `http://localhost:9000/newfile.tcx` then the file is downloaded (as `/uploads` is defined as a static directory in express), but the $location redirect above only returns me to the homepage, which is probably the result of:

```
.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) ->
    $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise '/'
```

What do I need to change in my uirouter config to let the file be downloaded (and then redirect to either `'/' or '/editor'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $location service changes the address in the address bar, but it doesn't ask the browser to load the resource located at this address. To do that, just uses the native window.location object:

```
window.location = 'http://localhost:9000/newfile.tcx';
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location